# Flash library for webcam recording, wrapped in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, webcam, flash-video

We want our users to be able to upload video streams to us, from their webcams. We're planning on using a service like [Infuxis](http://www.influxis.com) to handle the Flash Media Server side of things, but we need a client-side SWF that'll do the actual capturing.

Now, I know a little Flash, but not a lot. Ideally, I'd use an SWF that comes wrapped in a series of JS functions that'll allow me to control the process from within the browser (like [this jQuery webcam plugin](http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/)- but for video). Does anyone know of any?

Comment: I'm not sure you want to do this. If I got how it works, it streams images to JS. And then you'd want to send those images to the server? I think you'd better do a bit of Action script than adding an intermediate.

Comment: No, that isn't what I'm asking for- I don't want the upload itself to go through JS- that would still be done in Flash- I'd just have access to some JS functions (i.e. webcam.startRecording(), webcam.stopRecording()) that'll allow me to have the controls in the HTML rather than embedded in the SWF.

Comment: Ok, can't help you anyways...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check out cameratag.com. It provides a JS API for controlling a flash webcam recorder.

Answer (score 0):

[HDFVR](http://hdfvr.com/api) is a commercial video recording product developed in Flash (so the final file is a swf file) that - among other features - has a great set of JS and server side APIs:

- **JS control API** allows you to control HDFVR from JS
- **JS callback API** notifies you about events in the swf (connection succeeded, upload done)
- **PHP/ASP/.NET/etc. server side API** allows you to push the video info to the db

http://hdfvr.com/api

Answer (score 0):

[Camaratag](https://cameratag.com/) don't provide such an option so 
You can download swf file from camaratag  and save in local folder and  change path in camaratag js

```
 swfobject.embedSWF("local_path/camera.swf", dom_id+"_swf_placeholder", "100%", "100%", '11.1.0', 'https://'+appServer+'/'+CameraTag.version+'/expressInstall.swf', flashvars, params, attributes, checkSWF);
```

Comment: How to get the binary data from the recorded video? and to prevent automatic upload to cameratag server?